# Целесообразность капчи

Tags: защита, php

Привет погроммистам! Ребята, у меня на сайте будет так, что комментарии смогут оставлять только зарегистрированные пользователи. Необходима ли в этом случае капча для отправки комментария?

Comment: Ну где же вы, профессионалы? Подскажите, если я поставлю капчу, не задолбаю ли я этим прилежных зареганых человеков? Что насчет безопасности? К тому же у меня в комментах всегда будет поле hidden со случайными циферками.

Comment: спаммеры - они такие. Захотят - найдут дырку в любой защите.

Но кто мешает проверять только для первого десятка сообщений или если сообщение содержит ключевые слова.

Но как всегда - мой любимый способ - проверка на время - за сколько отправляется сообщение.

Но если хотите сделать действительно что то хорошее - отключите каптчи, но собирайте параметры сообщений (длина, время ответа, слова). Потом отметите, что из них - спам. А дальше - нейронная сеть.

Comment: @KoVadim, нейронная сеть не хотит работать. Я потратил 2 недели на создание движка+сам сайт. И уже 4-й день латаю возможные дыры. Поэтому и такие вопросики задаю. Я-то кто? Обычный штукатур, который иногда любит заниматься сайтами. ))) Спасибо за информацию, она совпадает со 2-м ответом. Будет идти в этом направлении дальше.))

Comment: @Deus, 

      Подскажите, если я поставлю капчу, не задолбаю ли я этим... 

конечно задолбаете, прикиньте, если бы здесь для комментария приходилось бы еще и в угадайку играть?

Я бы не остался.

Comment: @avp, вот поэтому я и задал вопрос. ответы я уже получил, поэтому напрягаю модераторов, чтобы оба ответа засчитать правильными.

Comment: @Deus, я думаю не стоит никого напрягать (ни администрацию здесь, ни участников капчей, там).

А оба автора ответов IMHO уже получили моральное удовлетворение от Вашего устремления поощрить их.

Comment: @avp, спасибо за понимание! просто я не погроммист вовсе. Я правозащитник. И делаю свой большой ресурс абсолютно бесплатно, использую минимум знаний по программированию. Поэтому задаю вопросы, которые кажутся иногда абсолютно детскими. Мне нужна поддержка. Моим первый ЭВМ был калькулятор МК-61. Стало быть, я просто хочу, чтобы восторжествовала справедливость.

Comment: > Привет **погроммистам**!

Не попадайтесь Розенталю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пользователь может зарегистрироваться и потом запустить флуд-программу, ведь у вас нет капчи для защиты от постинга. Сделайте так: если пользователь сделал более 5 сообщений в минуту, то у него появится капча.

Comment: как быть? не могу сосредоточиться. В БД создать табличку и в нее вносить время первого комментария, а затем после отправки коммента увеличивать счетчик... после 5-го выводить капчу... как потом очищать эти записи из базы в избежания засорения временными данными?

Comment: тааак, как мне поступить. Оба ответа правильны, дополняют друг друга. Я не могу оба ответа засчитать. Что мне делать?

Comment: @Deus, можете поступить вот так: создайте спам-лист, и при каждой отправке сообщения прогоняйте текст через этот лист. Если будет, допустим, 2 и более совпадений, то в следующий раз при отправке выводите капчу. А лучше всего использовать все два способа (5 раз и спам-лист), это увеличит вашу защиту от флуда и спама.

Comment: @SuperCreeper, я уже прописал на серверном скрипте проверку на идентичность постов (а вдруг человек случайно дважды отправил?). Дело не в этом. Дело в том, что я добиваюсь у админов засчитать ваш ответ и ответ второго погроммиста как правильные. Спасибо, ребята.

Answer (score 3):

зачем бд, держите информацию в сессии

Comment: ок, изначально session['count_comments'] = 0. затем я его увеличиваю до пяти. Показываю капчу, и обнуляю. Так?

Comment: нет, записывайте ещё время первого действия, капчу показывать в этом случае не обязательно, хватит и просто сообщения о правиле. просто не более  3х активных действий за минуту. если время больше минуты, то обнуляйте, если действий больше трех, то запрет.

Comment: @eicto, я не ошибаюсь, что вы имеете отношение к модерированию сайта? Я уже всех задолбал. Я бы хотел отметить оба ответа как правильные. Это дело чести. Поможете?

Comment: @Deus ошибаетесь. по крайней мере в этом я никак вам помочь не могу, у меня только карательные функции есть. просто обоим по плюсу поставьте.

Comment: @Deus: если вам нравятся ответы, поставьте для начала хоть плюсики за них, что ли?

Comment: @VladD, eicto проигнорировал предыдущий мой вопрос на предыдущий ваш комментарий. Если вы отключаете в браузере referer, а у меня серверный скрипт использует HTTP_REFERER, то что - работа сайта будет нарушена?

Comment: @eicto, ну, я вас часто доводил своими тупыми вопросами до крайней степени негодования, однако, карательных фишек я никогда не замечал.

Comment: @Deus: Угу. Сайт должен быть готов к тому, что referrer отсутствует или подделан. Он может содержать html-теги или sql-запросы в надежде на то, что вы вставите его в лог, который откроет админ на локальной машине, или вставите в базу данных не экранируя. Все данные, получаемые от пользователя, могут быть подделаны или отсутствовать.

Comment: @VladD я считаю нормальным не выдавать медиаданные клиентам с отсутвующим или внешним реферером, я как-бы повторюсь - нарушение клиенстским ПО протокола, ни сколько не обязывает программиста обрабатывать эти случаи. Я говорю о предоставлении информации, ни в коем случае не об авторизации.

Comment: @eicto: я ещё понимаю насчёт внешнего реферрера (хотлинкинг и все дела), а отсутствующий почему? Тот, кто отключил реферрер, может легко его и подделать. (Под лисичку даже [есть](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/referrer-control/) [аддоны](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/refcontrol/).)

Comment: так при чем здесь подделки, обычно реферер используется для ограничений хотлинка, чтобы никто не запостил картинку с сайта на популярный поиск с миллионом посещений, что приведет к неоправданой загрузке. то как тут использует рефрер @Deus мне вообще непонятно. подделка реферера не должна приводить к раскрытию данных, но и полное отключение рефереров не должно быть ожидаемым поведением клиента.

Comment: Забудьте о реферах. Я вам в referrer могу что угодно записать. Его есть смысл использовать только если для статистики.

Answer (score 2):

Я могу только высказать мнение как пользователь, не как разработчик.

Капча вообще злит. Но на ресурсах с анонимным постингом её ещё можно рассматривать как неизбежное зло. А вот капча, которую вынуждают вводить на сайте, где я зарегистрирован, бесит втройне. Если у Вашего будущего сайта не ожидается такой популярности, как у ЖЖ или вконтактика (что скорее всего), лучше обойтись без капчи. Лучше продумайте процедуру регистрации так, чтобы максимально затруднить её для ботов (например, задавать однократно какой-нибудь нетривиальный вопрос и время от времени его менять) и не создавать проблемы добропорядочным людям. Это тоже задача не очень лёгкая. Но в отличие от капчесадизма, благодарная.

Comment: @DarkHobbit, ресурс будет набирать команду людей, которым небезразлична судьба Украины и всего мира в целом. Борьба с коррупцией и "псевдовластью". Понятное дело, что начнутся атаки. Пишу от руки, чтобы знать каждую свою строчку программы. Сделал проверку на спам - если 3 комментария за 90 секунд - капча, -и снова доступные 90 секунд. "Жалобы" и "предложения" - не более одного сообщения в сутки от пользователя. ))) Еще лучше - сделать регистрацию только через емейл + капча. В общем, бедные пользователи... Но, оно того стоит.

Answer (score 0):

я ограничиваю по времени возможность добавления комментария. Для пользователя на js отсчет + на сервере программно. Не пройдешь такое.

Comment: + disabled форма воода

Comment: @abasov90, на хэш-коде ребята на 100% убедили меня, что любой ресурс должен работать без js так же, как и с js. (а у меня вообще все работало на скриптах - пришлось все переделывать). По времени - это хорошо. Но можно запрограммировать бота на отсылку комментария каждые, например, 2 минуты.))) Не правда ли?

Comment: @abasov90, "disabled форма воода" - чтобы у пользователя истерика случилась?